# Why I can't update the UI when binding a class inherits the interface?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to write a demo of binding a class inherits the interface.
Here is the code of interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App1
{
    public interface BaseClass
    {
        string AAA { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is code-behind of the Page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public BaseClass BC;
        public static MainPage MP;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MP = this;
            BC = new ChildClass();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        public class ChildClass : BaseClass
        {
            string _AAA = "123";
            public string AAA
            {
                get { return _AAA; }
                set { _AAA = value; MP.RaisePropertyChanged("AAA"); }
            }

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BC.AAA = "456";
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is the XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind BC.AAA,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="Button_Click">123</Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

After I ran the program, it will display the default string of AAA successfully. However, when I clicked the button, it can't change the text to "456".
I wonder if there is the INotifyPropertyChanged problem. But I don't know what's wrong with it.
Would you please tell me what's wrong with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 mistakes:

**First:**

Notice that the `ChidClass` calls to `MP.RaisePropertyChanged("AAA")`, not the `BaseClass`. So, instead of declaring BC like

`public BaseClass BC;`

do

`public ChildClass BC;` instead.

**Second:**
the property `AAA` doesn't belong to `MainPage` class, it belongs to `ChildClass`, so instead of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `MainPage`, implement it in the `ChildClass`:

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _AAA = "123";
    public string AAA
    {
        get { return _AAA; }
        set { _AAA = value; RaisePropertyChanged("AAA"); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

This should work.

**Edit:**
The first mistake you made, if it was on intention, because you want to bind the UIs to this interface, then **Sorry, you can't do that**.

Why? because, to achieve that, you need to raise `INotifyPropertyChanged` event in that interface, but interfaces in c# (currently c# 7.3) doesn't let you do any default implementation, which means you can't write any code to raise that event. Having said that, C# 8.0, which is coming in near future, will have this capability. Can you wait till then?

Comment: I modified it as you said and it worked. But the most important question is the first mistake you said, that's what I do it intentionally. I wanna binding an interface to the UI, whenever someone inherits the interface and set it to the public BaseClass BC, the UI will automatically update with the new class.

Comment: Anyhow, the UI and interface are in a dll which to reference by other program, so that I have to binding the interface to UI and let others to update the UI by creating a new class which inherit the interface. Would you please tell me how I can do this, thank you.

Comment: Someone told me that I can use an abstract class to do it, I tried but failed. Now I think I can only set a property to the binding and change the property via the class. Thank you.

Comment: Yes , he/she is right. An abstract class can do that. If you have no problem with abstract classes, then go on.